# Send results to specificed page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I was wondering how to send a key that was pressed on the keyboard, to a result page but in the background so that the user can't see when you send the key until the user cames to the last page of the "test". I already have a function that detects which key that was pressed and it displays the key on the screen and it looks like this:

```
document.onkeypress = function(e) {
   e = e || window.event;
   var charCode = e.charCode || e.keyCode,
       character = String.fromCharCode(charCode);

   consoloe.log(charCode);

   if(e.charCode == 98 || e.keyCode == 98) {
      document.write("B = " + charCode + "<br>");
   } else if(e.charCode == 114 || e.keyCode == 114) {
   document.write("R = " + charCode + "<br>");
   }
};
```

But what I want it to do is just send this **without** displaying it in the next page like in the background, but instead more like showing it in a result page and save it there so that the user can see the results **after** the test has finished. Here is one part of the test so you can see how it looks like and the result page that I would like to send it to:

Exercise1.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Exercise1</title>
<style>
#first-child {
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   background: white;
   margin-top: 150px;
   margin-bottom: 50px;
   margin-right: 0px;
   margin-left: 550px;
   -webkit-animation: myfirst 1s;
   -moz-animation: myfirst 1s;
   animation: myfirst 1s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes myfirst {
    0% {background: white;}
   20% {background: white;}
   40% {background: white;}
   60% {background: white;}
   80% {background: white;}
  100% {background: red;}
}
@keyframes myfirst {
    0% {background: white;}
   20% {background: white;}
   40% {background: white;}
   60% {background: white;}
   80% {background: white;}
  100% {background: red;}
}
.first-parent {
    color: blue;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    margin-left: 600px;
    margin-right: 0px;
}
.second-parent {
    color: red;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-right: 0px;
}
p {
    margin-left: 640px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id='first-child'></div>
<button class="first-parent">B</button>
<button class="second-parent">R</button>
<br />
<p>1/2</p>

<script>
document.onkeypress = function(e) {
   e = e || window.event;
   var charCode = e.charCode || e.keyCode,
   character = String.fromCharCode(charCode);

   console.log(charCode);

   if(e.charCode == 98 || e.keyCode == 98) {
       document.write("B = " + charCode + "<br>");
   } else if(e.charCode == 114 || e.keyCode == 114) {
       document.write("R = " + charCode + "<br>");
   }
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Result.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset= utf-8>
<title>Result</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>This is the results</h1>
<script>

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

HTML, jQuery and JavaScript is my thing I don't know PHP or something like that so no PHP solutions and I can't use any other keypress solution because this is the only keypress that actully works on my computer. Thanks in advance, peace!

Comment: You can store them in `cookies` or `local storage`

Comment: you could use local storage to store the keys or send them as hidden inputs on the page, how many pages are you storing across ? is it just till the next page /

Comment: Nope I have 2 Exercises and 50 test pages

Comment: But the exercises isn't necessary

Comment: @madforstrength I tried cookies once but I don't really understand that could you explain and send a code, if you don't mind ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following functions to set and get values of cookies in javascript:

```
<script>
function ll_set_cookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}
function ll_get_cookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) != -1) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
    return "";
}
</script>
```

When you want to set cookie just call the function like

`ll_set_cookie('Q1','A','1')`

Where

```
Q1 is your question number
A is the selected answer 
And cookie will be stored for 1 day
```

Then on the final page you can get the answer of each question like:

```
ll_get_cookie('Q1');
```

Comment: How do I display the cookie ? And where should I call it ? I have no idea how to handle cookies :p